# Is it possible to capture the content outside/between shortcodes?

Tags: shortcode

What I mean is... if I passed the following into do_shortcode() could I get access to the HTML in this?

```
<p>First paragraph</p>
[shortcode1][/shortcode1]
<p>Another paragraph</p>
<p>Another paragraph</p>
[shortcode2][/shortcode2]
```

My hope would be to have two blocks of HTML to play with:

```
<p>First paragraph</p>
```

and

```
<p>Another paragraph</p>
<p>Another paragraph</p>
```

Almost like if I could call a function called do_html() or do_content() and process these chunks.

Comment: What are you trying to build that requires this? It probably is possible, but it would involve a lot of string manipulation and modifying the shortcode parser, it won't be easy or nice, and will have to deal with nested shortcodes. If we knew what the end goal you're trying to achieve via this was, it would be easier to answer ( as well as alternatives, you may be trying to build something that already exists )

Comment: Thank you for answering, and asking the question I hoped you wouldn't ask ;) True, my reason isn't purely Wordpress XD. I was playing with do_shortcode for my own purposes and seeing if I could put a WYSIWYG editor at the places where there was HTML and form fields where there were shortcodes. Completely unnecessary really.

Comment: Sounds like something easy to do with the block editor by building form blocks